# Is there a way to select this name from more than one table?

Tags: sql

I need to select the item name and the vendor name for each item that belongs to the vendor with a rating bigger than 4. And I can't find a way, I know it's something with joins but the 2 of them have the same column name.

```
CREATE TABLE venedors(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar2(20),
rating int)


CREATE TABLE items(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar2(20),
venedorId int references venedors(id))
```

Comment: Sethei, better you show us what u tried so we can help explain where it went wrong, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

If i understanded your problem.

```
Select items.name as itemName, venedors.name as vendorName
from items
inner join venedors
on items.venedorId  = venedors.id
where venedors.rating > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all the vendors irrespective whether there are items associated with vendors or not, then try with left join as shown below:

```
Select v.name as vendorName, i.name as itemName
from venedors v
left join items i
on i.venedorId  = v.id
where v.rating > 4
```